# How to place the mouse cursor in the center of the screen using python

Tags: python, pygame, kivy, mouse

## I use python Kivy, is it possible to put the mouse cursor in the center of the screen every time a clock event occurs?

something like:

- `pygame.mouse.set_pos()` - I would not like to mix kivy and pygame in
  my project, but if there are no alternatives, then only this option
  remains
- `pyautogui.dragTo()` - this method works but reduces performance

in the Kivy documentation I didn't find any ways other than

- `Window.mouse_pos = [x, y]`

But it doesn't have any effect

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using `pyautogui.moveTo()` function

```
height = 1920
width = 1080
pyautogui.moveTo(height / 2, width / 2)
```

Comment: This greatly slows down my app

Comment: @miriskrit so there is no other way besides these functions. You are using the autopygui so the fastest method will be inbuild.

Comment: Extending possible with size = pyautogui.size()
pyautogui.moveTo(size.width / 2, size.height / 2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ctypes` and `pyautogui` for this:

```
import ctypes #For get resolution of the screen
import pyautogui #To move your cursor in the middle of the screen 

center_res = ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0)/2, ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)/2 #x and y cordinates are divided by two to fall in the center of the screen (for any monitor)
pyautogui.moveTo(center_res) #Simpli move your cursor =)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).